# Teamcity error - Image does not exist in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, teamcity, agent

I am using teamcity server 8.0.3 (build 27540) and have set up several git projects. I am using Amazon EC2 images which are set up as cloud agents.

My setup starts up the agents and runs the tests on them when a new job is put to the queue.

I got it working fine for weeks and have not touched the server, and suddenly it stopped working.

In the cloud  tabs I now get "Image error" with the message: "Image does not exist in Amazon EC2". Even though the image exists there!

If I open and save or re-create my cloud agent settings then one of the agents will be awoken by teamcity and do builds just fine, but the warning is still there and when the agent shuts down after my time delay I have to re-save the cloud agent settings to force a start on the agent.

I have tried restarting Teamcity with no avail.

This is the errors from teamcity-cloud.log

```
[2013-12-12 06:11:00,850]   WARN [rome'{id=cp3} 1] - .clouds.amazon.image.ImageBase - Failed to fetch data of image AmazonImageInstance{id=i-d123cd29, amazonId=ami-463edb31} from EC2. Image does not exist in Amazon EC2 
[2013-12-12 06:11:00,958]   INFO [ue; Flush Queue] - .instances.StartInstanceAction - Starting cloud instance: profile 'EC2 TC Win Chrome'{id=cp3}, AmazonImageInstance{id=i-d123cd29, amazonId=ami-463edb31}, hash=EZObYYzWwxDOZ4o9svYSvGbdLqf5e7KQ, reason=Automatic start: Compatible with queued build Booking Log Client :: Win Chrome(promotionId=12008) 
[2013-12-12 06:11:01,565]   INFO [ue; Flush Queue] - .server.impl.CloudEventsLogger - Cloud instance start succeeded: profile 'EC2 TC Win Chrome'{id=cp3}, Amazon Instance{instanceId=i-d123cd29, imageId=i-d123cd29, amazonImageId=ami-463edb31, status: Scheduled to start} 
[2013-12-12 06:11:03,135]   INFO [rome'{id=cp3} 1] - r.impl.DBCloudStateManagerImpl - Image: i-d123cd29, Instance: i-d123cd29 is marked with state: running. 
[2013-12-12 06:12:18,441]   WARN [uled executor 4] - .instances.StoppedInstanceTask - Instance has changed status from stopped to Running: Amazon Instance{instanceId=i-d123cd29, imageId=i-d123cd29, amazonImageId=ami-463edb31, status: Running}, profile 'EC2 TC Win Chrome'{id=cp3} 
[2013-12-12 06:12:20,759]   WARN [rome'{id=cp3} 1] - .clouds.amazon.image.ImageBase - Failed to fetch data of image AmazonImageInstance{id=i-d123cd29, amazonId=ami-463edb31} from EC2. Image does not exist in Amazon EC2 
[2013-12-12 06:13:04,668]   INFO [nio-8111-exec-9] - r.impl.DBCloudStateManagerImpl - Image: AmazonImageInstance{id=i-d123cd29, amazonId=ami-463edb31}, profile: profile 'EC2 TC Win Chrome'{id=cp3} was marked to CONTAIN agent 
[2013-12-12 06:13:04,672]   INFO [nio-8111-exec-9] - .server.impl.CloudEventsLogger - Detected cloud agent EC2-i-d123cd29 {id=24, host=10.254.1.23:9090, agentTypeId=122, pool=Win Chrome}, profile 'EC2 TC Win Chrome'{id=cp3}, Amazon Instance{instanceId=i-d123cd29, imageId=i-d123cd29, amazonImageId=ami-463edb31, status: Running}
```

and from teamcity-server.log

```
[2013-12-12 06:13:04,648]   WARN -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Agent EC2-i-dd123cd29 is unauthorized with comment: Cloud instance (id=i-dd123cd29, imageId=i-dd123cd29, profileId=cp3) has gone (is not reported by cloud profile) 
[2013-12-12 06:13:04,661]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Agent has been registered: EC2-i-dd123cd29 {id=24, host=10.254.1.23:9090, agentTypeId=122, pool=Win Chrome}, not running a build 
[2013-12-12 06:13:04,690]   INFO - tbrains.buildServer.ACTIVITIES - Agent "EC2-i-dd123cd29 {id=24, host=10.254.1.23:9090, agentTypeId=122, pool=Win Chrome}" was authorised with comment "Virtual agent is authorized automatically." 
[2013-12-12 06:13:05,022]   INFO - tbrains.buildServer.ACTIVITIES - Build started; Booking Log Client :: Win Chrome {id=booking_log_client, internal id=bt18} #34 {build id=6213, promotion id=12008, branch=<default>, history=false, agent=EC2-i-dd123cd29 {id=24, host=10.254.1.23:9090, agentTypeId=122, pool=Win Chrome}, triggered by "Nisse Nilsson" (##userId='10'). Started Thu Dec 12 06:13:04 UTC 2013} 
[2013-12-12 06:13:57,586]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Agent description updated for agent: EC2-i-dd123cd29 {id=24, host=10.254.1.23:9090, agentTypeId=122, pool=Win Chrome} 
[2013-12-12 06:23:54,323]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Agent description updated for agent: EC2-i-dd123cd29 {id=24, host=10.254.1.23:9090, agentTypeId=122, pool=Win Chrome}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears due to:
The AMI 'ami-463edb31' is no longer available in EC2's 'EU (Ireland)' region.

source:https://aws.amazon.com/amis/amazon-public-images-basic-microsoft-windows-server-2008-64-bit